# how to pass username in html email template in django using msg.send()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-allauth, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am new to Django coding. I am currently working on DRF Django Rest Framework along with API. I have been trying to send a HTML email template with attachment as soon as the user register . I have achieved sending the same but i want to pass the dynamic contents like email of the user registered to the HTML email template from views.py , But unable to do it. I am using msg.send().

IN VIEWS.PY:

```
def attachment(request):
   queryset = User.objects.all()
   em=[]
   h=[]
   for star in queryset.iterator():
       em.append(star.email)
   print(em)    
   h=em[-1]
   msg = mail.EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject = 'attachment',
        body = 'Hi, Welcome!',
        from_email = 'anushstella97@gmail.com',
        to = [h],
        connection = con
        )
   msg.attach_file('C:/Users/hp/Downloads/APIV1-master/APIV1- 
     master/polls/img.jpg')
   msg_html = render_to_string('C:/Users/hp/Anaconda3/Lib/site- 
  packages/allauth/templates/account/email/email_confirmation_message.html' 
  , {"email": request.user.email})

   msg.send()
   return HttpResponse('<h1>Created</h1>')
```

IN HTML TEMPLATE:

```
<p>Thanks for signing up! We're excited to have you as an early user.</p>
                <p> Your registered email is : </p>
                <p>
                    <strong> {{ email }} </strong></p>
```

Comment: What happens, does `h` get the intended value? I can see an error there, you pass `context` and not `content` to `attach_alternative`.

Comment: h gets the email string to which the email is to be sent.  I want to pass the same. I changed context to content but its still the same.

Comment: Ok, so what's the issue? You just add to the context dictionary whatever you want to populate the email template with. If by "email of the user registered" you mean the user making the request you can do `request.user.email`

Comment: I s my html code fine?

Comment: It is if you want it to say that & show an email address defined as `h`

Comment: yes i am sending email via variable h to the html file and to be printed in {{h}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render the template you can use `render_to_string` from `from django.template.loader` and pass the context variables along with it..

E.g.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
html = render_to_string("account/email/email_confirmation_message.html", {"email": request.user.email})
```

Inside email_confirmation_message.html:

```
Hi {{ email }},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from osaat_az.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
```

```py
# send email
def send_email(receiver, subject, content):
    try:

        msg = EmailMessage(
            subject,
            content,
            EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            [receiver]
        )
        msg.content_subtype = "html"
        msg.send()

    except:
        print(f"Couldn't send the email")
```

```py
# get email content dynamically by passing variables

def get_html_content(file_path: str, **kwargs):
    
    html_content = render_to_string(file_path, kwargs)

    return html_content
```

Now you can import the two functions above, anywhere you want, and use them.
Let's say the above functions are located in `utils.py` and at the same directory you want to use them in `views.py`.

In `views.py`:
You can use this to send the email:

```py
from accounts.utils import get_html_content
from .utils import send_email
import os

premium_package_duration = 5  # for simplicity, you will have something dynamic
email_subject = "Example subject for email"
user_email_content = get_html_content(os.path.join(current_path,'templates', 'home', 'product_premium_renewal_notification.html'), duration=premium_package_duration)
send_email(user_email, email_subject, user_email_content)
```